# How to insert primary key second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I'm retrieving data from single html form and inserting it into two different SQL table `USER` and `PAYMENT_DETAILS`, I made a foreign key in `PAYMENT_DETAILS` table, now I'm confused how to add a primary key of `USER` table into the `PAYMENT_DETAILS` table

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
  $gender=$_POST['gender'];
  $datofbirth=$_POST['dateofbirth'];
  $primary_email=$_POST['primary_email'];
  $Email_Confirm=$_POST['Email_Confirm'];
  $phone=$_POST['contact'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $confirmpassword=$_POST['confirmpassword'];
  $username= $_POST['username'];
  $status=2;

  //payment information 
  $ownername=$_POST['ownername'];
  $cvvnumber=$_POST['cvvnumber'];
  $cardnumber=$_POST['cardnumber'];
  $cardtype=$_POST['cardtype'];
  $expirydate=$_POST['expirydate'];
  $balance=$_POST['money'];

   $mysql_get_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user where username='$username'");
  $get_rows = mysql_affected_rows($conn);

    if($get_rows >=1)
        {
          echo "user exists";die();
        }     
  else
    {
         $query1= mysql_query("
         INSERT INTO 
         user
            (firstname,lastname,gender,datofbirth,primary_email,contact,password,username,status)

              VALUES
                    ('$firstname','$lastname','$gender','$datofbirth','$primary_email','$phone','$password','$username','$status')");

    $query2 = mysql_query("
      INSERT INTO 
      payment_details
                    (Owner_Name,CVV_Numer,Card_Number,Card_Balance,Card_Type,Validation)
       VALUES 
             ('$ownername','$cvvnumber','$cardnumber','$balance','$cardtype','$expirydate')");
```

Comment: add column user_id in payment_details. Try is mysql_insert_id(). Details http://php.net/manual/tr/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: will it work at the time registration when the the user isnt registerd yet?

Comment: Added a few tags, but surely this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

that php function gives the last entered record's primary key.(put the function after the first query. that means, it will give first entered primary key.)

```
 mysql_insert_id();
```